# Android statusbar notification load sd icon

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

Is it possible to load external (stored on SD) icons to show on statusbar?

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, message,System.currentTimeMillis());
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. That's not possible.

The `Notification` class stores icon references [as a resid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#icon). Graphics on the external storage can not be accessed this way.

Comment: @bobbean No problem, glad I could help. If this was helpful, please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). *(just in case you are not aware of this mechanism)*